# Antenna polarization and antenna directivity are the same?

Tags: antenna, communication, wireless, rfid

I'm working on an RFID project, and looking for information about the antennas that I have to use, I have the following doubt: Antenna polarization and antenna directiivity are the same? Thanks!

Comment: No they are not the same.

Comment: We need a lot more information to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Polarization refers to the relative angles of the electric and magnetic fields along the path of propagation.

Directivity refers to the gain of the antenna at various angles relative to its own axis.